# How to Execute Script After Download?

Tags: shell, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe

The code below is supposed to download a script and execute it on a vagrant guest. The script is downloaded, but never run. Does anyone know how to ensure execution of the shell script after download?

```
remote_file "/home/vagrant/conscript_setup.sh" do
  source "#{node.default['conscript']['url']}"
  notifies :run, "bash[install conscript]", :immediately
end

bash "install conscript" do
  cwd "/home/vagrant"
  code <<-EOH
    cwd "/home/vagrant"
    chown vagrant:vagrant conscript_setup.sh
    chmod 777 conscript_setup.sh
    conscript_setup.sh
  EOH
end
```

Comment: can you add code to confirm that script is installed and chmoded correctly? Good luck

Comment: Without an explicit path to your `conscript_setup.sh`, bash tries to search for it in the `$PATH` (where it probably doesn't find it). Thus, try to run the script with an explicit path as `./conscript_setup.sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the script, you need the full (absolute) path as it is not in your shell's execute path.

I have a working example (similar), for your reference

```rb
temp=Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]

remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/screenfetch.sh" do
  source "https://raw.github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/master/screenfetch-dev"
  mode 00755
end

bash 'screenfetch' do
  code <<-EOF
    #{temp}/./screenfetch.sh > #{temp}/screenfetch.log 2>/dev/null
  EOF
end
```

mode bit is set at download time. You can change your recipe accordingly.

BTW: You can enable debug to see more information

For `chef-solo` => `chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json -l debug`

Vagrant + Chef Solo example (use `chef.arguments`)

```rb
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  # vagrant + chef-solo provision log level
  # equivalent to VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up
  chef.arguments = "-l debug"
  chef.add_recipe "apt"
  chef.add_recipe "nginx"
end
```

If `chef-arguments` does NOT work, just `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up`

Comment: Omg, genius! The Google Gods have blessed today, my friend. I spent 2 hours yesterday searching/trying to figure this out, but with Chef's perplexing documentation, I never could. (Why they have so many commands that can seemingly do the exact same things, I'll never understand... [template, script, bash, execute]). Never even came across remote_file until now. Solved this within 5 minutes of coming to work today... "vagrant provision shell chef equivalent" did the trick :)